# Quick minor explanation of Android services?

Tags: android, android-service

I apologize up-front if this is a really obvious question since I'm pretty sure I'm over-thinking it.

Anyway, I'm building a music player in Android which basically streams playlists from 8Tracks and, as my understanding is, the best-practice here would be using a foreground service. I've already built everything and it's completely functional sans service, however, I'm a little confused as to how to implement the service.

As is, I have my Player class, which controls the MediaPlayer, extending Service but I'm not quite sure where to progress from there. I've tried binding it to my Engine class which reconciles all the background work with the UI, however I keep getting a ServiceConnectionLeaked exception, and I'm fairly certain this is simply the wrong approach.

I would appreciate any help at all; really a nod in the right direction is all I need. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can directly control MediaPlayer without additional Player class. As I know MediaPlayer is already a service so you can use start and stop methods to play something.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize MediaPlayer was already a service, that makes a lot of sense. As for the custom class, it's basically a wrapper because I have to do some other processing and what not when playing the playlist and it just made the most sense to bundle it into a custom class. Thanks so much though, I'll look into the service component of MediaPlayer!

Comment: The media player is NOT a service. Read the Google Documentation and Best Practices.